# Change of Variables from [0,1] to an arbitrary measurable set

Tags: measure-theory

For any measurable $E\subset\mathbb{R}$ with measure 1, does there exist a function
$T:[0,1]\to E$ such that $T([0,1])=E$, and if $f$ is Lebesgue integrable,
$$∫_Ef=\int_{[0,1]}f∘T$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so this might be more generality than you're looking for and I feel like there's probably a simpler answer for this special case but...

Theorem 16 in Chapter 15 of Royden's "Real Analysis" states that if $\mu$ is a normalized (meaning it gives the whole space measure 1) Borel measure on a separable, uncountable (both are automatically true of $E$ in your case) non-atomic (meaning singletons have measure zero), and complete metric space (so let's assume $E$ is closed), then this measure space is measurably isomorphic (meaning there's a bijection that preserves the $\sigma$-algebra as well as the measure, $\mu$) to $[0,1]$, endowed with the Lebesgue measure.

This bijection, $T$, will satisfy your equation because it is measure preserving.

Comment: Great! I wish $E$ were closed - but this is close enough! Nice find.

Comment: @David, Thanks! Great question. And yeah I feel like one should be able to get rid of "$E$ has to be closed" by approximating $E$ from within by closed sets or something.

Comment: ah - nice point.